# php : sorting chronogically an array of string representing dates

Tags: php, sorting, date

how could i convert this exemple of string values array:

```
$taba=array('12/04/12','13/05/13','03/01/12');
```

to date type values, sort these dates chronogically before returning them as strings in a select option HTML input ?

Comment: So converting to some kind of date type is not really required, but rather your thoughts on how sorting could be accomplished?

Comment: What do you mean by date type values ? Unix int or other ?

Comment: Why you didnt accepted my answer? its correct, you accepted answer, which takes wrong date format 03/01/12, read comment below his answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$taba=array('12/04/12','13/05/13','03/01/12');
function todate($date){
     // as Legionar comment your date format is wrong .. can't guess which is date, which is year..
     // if year is the last numbers you must change the return to ..
     // return strtotime(implode("-",array_reverse(explode("/",$date))));
     return strtotime(str_replace("/","-",$date));
}

$map = array_map('todate', $taba);
sort($map);
echo "<select>";
foreach($map as $key=>$value) {
    echo '<option>'.date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $value)."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

Sorry I missed the sort point. Here is with sorting :)
You can generate the wished date format at the foreach date function..

Comment: Your code is wrong! Your function todate takes $taba in format Y/m/d, but his format is d/m/Y. I.e. your answer takes 03/01/12 as 12th January 2003, but it is 3rd January 2012...

Comment: You are right. But why you are sure that its not 12-01-2003 ?
Its not correct format.. only the code developer can know what will come to him..

Answer (score 4):

Here you are (sorted from past to the future):

```
$taba=array('12/04/12','13/05/13','03/01/12');
$tabb=array();

foreach ($taba as $key => $val) {
    $d = explode('/', $val);

    $tabb[$key] = $d[2].'-'.$d[1].'-'.$d[0];
}

asort($tabb);

echo '<select>';
    foreach ($tabb as $key => $val) {
        echo '<option value="'.$val.'">'.$taba[$key].'</option>';
    }
echo '</select>';
```

Comment: Why do you need `$key => $val` ?

Comment: because he wanted to have it written in his string format (d/m/Y), but sorted through Y-m-d format. You have to have there two arrays. First check, then minus.

Comment: You can not use key-value for $taba, it's not an associative array.

Comment: @JohnSmith: That's incorrect. You *can* use `$key => $value` for non-associative arrays. See http://3v4l.org/CY3KA

Comment: Ahh, okay. But still why will I do it when I can avoid it? Sorry

Answer (score 3):

As variant, you can use `strtotime()` for converting each element to timestamp, than sort how you need and transform back before output. Example:

> ```
> $taba=array('12/04/12','13/05/13','03/01/12');
> usort($taba, function($a, $b){
>     $ta = strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $a));
>     $tb = strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $b));
>     if ($ta == $tb) {
>         return 0;
>     }
>     return ($ta < $tb) ? -1 : 1;
> });
> print_r($taba);
> ```

Comment: The only problem being that `strtotime` will not parse this particular format correctly...

Comment: Try adding at strtotime() str_replace("/","-",$var)
because current format can't be parsed correctly. when there is / I think its m/d/Y .

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`array_map`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to get a timestamp for each input date, then [`array_multisort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) to reorder the dates based on the sorted order of the corresponding timestamps:

```
$taba=array('12/04/12','13/05/13','03/01/12');
$timestamps = array_map(function($d) {
    return DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y', $d)->getTimestamp(); }, $taba);
array_multisort($timestamps, $taba);

print_r($taba);
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/MK1Xx2)**.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not worried about invalid dates and all dates have a consistent format, might I suggest you use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) with a custom compare function that sorts the dates however you wish e.g.:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
  $year = strcmp(substr($a, -2), substr($b, -2));
  if ($year == 0) {
    // years are the same, try month
    $month = strcmp(substr($a, 3, 2), substr($b, 3, 2));
    if ($month == 0) {
      return strcmp(substr($a, 0, 2), substr($b, 3, 2));
    }
    return $month;
  }
  return $year;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$taba=array('12/04/12','13/05/13','03/01/12');

usort(
    $taba,
    function ($valueA, $valueB) {
        return preg_replace('#(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)#', '$3$2$1', $valueA) > 
            preg_replace('#(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)#', '$3$2$1', $valueB);
    }
);

var_dump($taba);
```